# Microsoft OpenID Connect: send the sign-in request issue doesn't require users to enter password

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm trying to configure OpenID Connect (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc) in my custom web app that allows users to sign in with microsoft personal accounts. I went into an issue that the sign-in request doesn't require user to enter the password, and it will redirect user to the redirect url after entering the username. I registered an application in azure portal, and chose the account type "account type: Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)"

Here's my sign-in request, and I configured msn.com in redirect url for testing purpose. Any ideas what did I miss?

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=4463b035-1647-457f-89d1-baa095d3b078&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.msn.com&scope=openid
```

Please advise!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I try the [`Implicit grant flow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#send-the-sign-in-request) like what you do.
When I request the URL and don't enter the password, I face the issue shown in the screenshot.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=openid&nonce=678910
```

[image]

It seems you have signed in, you could delete the sign in cookies and try again.

---

**Update:**

Is this account that you choose? If you pick the account that has signed in, you will don't need to enter the password. You could click `Use another account`, then enter username and password to sign in.

I chose this account type, and Implicit grant flow is what your [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-the-sign-in-request) uses.

[image]

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I double check, and I didn't enable Implicit grant. I deleted the cookies, and even tried  with different browser, and I still didn't see the password prompt. I want the user needs to enter both username and password in the microsoft login page before redirecting to redirect_url. any ideas what did I miss here?

Comment: @Kate Could you provide some screenshots? I followed the request URL like yours and it worked.

Comment: I got microsoft user name page, and then go to redirect URL without showing password page. That's it. Just to clarify, did you choose the account type "account type: Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)"  and didn't enable "Implicit Grant Flow" ? Thanks again

Comment: @Kate Hi, kate! Maybe you use the `Pick an account`. Please see my update in the answer.